# Drag and Drop + Input file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a HTML5 image uploader following this article:
http://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop

The problem is that I would like to offer the drag and drop and the input file, the both options for the user. On this article he explains how to use only one or the other. I already noticed that the difference is

```
var files = evt.target.files;        // Input file
var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;  // Drag and Drop
```

Do you have idea how to make the both work together?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Nothing stops you from including both in your page. They need separate elements and event listeners

Comment: Have you tried including both at the same time?

Comment: I just tried evt.target.dataTransfer.files; I also tried to repeat a part of the function. The both didn't work.

Comment: Leaving a feedback, I gave up about this solution and now I'm using the Dropzone JS (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) instead. Is a nice plugin.